# Unable to launch RStudio (Fresh installation) on windows 7 OS (SP1)

Tags: rstudio

I just installed Rstudio on my *windows 7* machine, while trying to launch the application for the 1st time I get the error message as `“Application stopped running”`, I was never able to launch the application.

**Troubleshooting Steps followed**

1. Check Graphic card drivers, updated the windows patches and all the drivers are up-to-date.
2. Checked the DLL files (ig75icd64.dll ), which also present in windows32 folder.
3. Uninstalled/reinstalled and rebooted the multiple time
4. R application is working fine, but not the Rstudio

Software Info:
R Version : 3.6.1
Rstudio : 1.2.5 (Desktop Version)

Now I need help in fixing the issue, Please advise!

Error Message are given below:

**Problem signature**

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: rstudio.exe
  Application Version:  1.2.5019.0
  Application Timestamp:    5db1e0e4
  Fault Module Name:    ig75icd64.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.18.10.4425
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5702a9ad
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000017143a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: e52e
  Additional Information 2: e52e2780b500f2b41eafa296aa17a677
  Additional Information 3: 63be
  Additional Information 4: 63bead1da0d8da840e5be281271dd92a
```

**System Info**

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
System Type:             x64-based PC
Chip type:                 Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Current Mode:      1366 x 768 (32 bit) (50Hz)
Monitor Name:     LCD 1366x768
Driver Name:         igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32
Driver File Version:  10.18.0010.4425 (English)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed !

I used older Version 1.1.463 RStudio, Now i was able to launch the application on Windows 7

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio